# Filter objects from a table based on ManyToMany field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a messaging app.
The models are as follows.

```
class ChatRoom(SafeDeleteModel):
  _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE

  room_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
  participants = models.ManyToManyField(User)

 class Meta:
    db_table = TABLE_PREFIX + "chat_room"


class Message(SafeDeleteModel):
  _safedelete_policy = SOFT_DELETE_CASCADE

  chat_room = models.ForeignKey(ChatRoom, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  message = models.TextField()
  sent_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)

 class Meta:
    db_table = TABLE_PREFIX + "chat_message"
```

I have to filter ChatRoom object which contains a list of users.

Eg: On sending data like this to the api

```
{
  "participants": [2,3]
}
```

It should return a ChatRoom object which contains both user '2' and user '3' as participants.

I had tried filtering it with

```
room = ChatRoom.objects.filter(participants__in=serializer.validated_data['participants'])
```

but it returns a list of room objects with user '1' and user '2'.

I had also tried using get() but it returns an error.

What am I doing wrong and how can i do it right?

Thanks for looking into my problem. Hope you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using Query..

```
ChatRoom.objects.filter(participants__in=serializer.validated_data['participants'])
```

1. **filter** function returns **a list of objects** of the model matching the conditions.
2. **get** function only return **a single object** of model and if none or more than one item matches the condition then an exception is thrown. That is why get is only used for candidate keys or unique resultant conditions.

In your case, I suppose both participants can be part of many rooms, also there might be a possibility that there is no such room. if you want only one queryset to be returned you can use this.

```
room_list= ChatRoom.objects.filter(participants__in=serializer.validated_data['participants']
if len(room_list) >0:
   room = room_list[0]
else:
   room = None
```

This will return the first room in which all the given participants are present, you can replace 0 with any valid value or add something more in the query if you want it to return a specific room.